# How do I add in-floor heating to a small area?

Tags: heating, floor

I get extremely cold feet, and have radiant heating in some rooms of my house, and I love it.

I spend a few hours a day in a room without radiant heat.  Is there a way to heat about two square feet of floor space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are heated floor mats that you can buy.  We use them at desks in our warehouse.  There's not much of a color choice but sizes do vary.  You can either get them at office supplies or diy's.  Search for 'heated floor mats' for internet goodness.

[image: Heated floor mats]

Comment: Is this the one you use?

Comment: Ours were all rubber(?) like a standing mat.  It was more industrial looking.  I haven't worked in the warehouse for years but we have had them for years and they still work.  We got ours through Grainger's more than likely.

Answer (score 7):

There are small radiant heat mats commonly used under tile in  bathrooms. These are electric and can be thermostatically controlled. They are safe to use under carpet and thin type wood flooring.  The mats are apx 30inches by 15 inches and can be connected together to cover the desired area. Both the heater mats and controllers are avail at the home improvement stores or any flooring specialty store.

Comment: Thanks,  Just to be clear, I  plan to use this on the floor, not under it.  Can you give me something I could search for?  (I know SE is not for shopping recommendations...)